# Powershell взять почту из одного домена, прикрепить к учеткке в другом

Tags: email, powershell, active-directory

Добрый день! Помогите, пжалста, разобраться. Ситуация - есть два домена, в одном учетки сотрудников названы цифрами, в другом - нормальными фио. У этих учеток везде прикручена одна и таже почта. Нужно вытать список пользователей в группе в одном домене, и через почту прицепить нормальное фио. И сделать в одну строчку бы это все.

```
$ctrlGroup = Get-ADGroup -SearchBase $base1 -Server $server1  -Filter {name -like "groups-users*"} -Properties info

$user1 = Get-ADGroupMember -Server $server -Identity $ctrlGroup.Name | Get-ADUser -Properties Mail | Select-Object Mail).mail

Get-ADUser -Server $server2 -Filter "mail -eq '$user1'" -Properties samaccountname).samaccountname
```

Как-то эти команды нужно в 1 запихнуть...

Comment: зачем все так усложнять? почему нельзя 3 команды выполнить ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй так:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADGroup -Server $server1 $group -Properties Member |select -ExpandProperty Member|%{
    Get-ADUser -Server $server1 -Filter {DistinguishedName -eq $_} -Properties mail,DisplayName|%{
        #получаем нужные данные из объекта
        $DisplayName = $_.DisplayName
        Get-ADUser -Server $server2 -Filter {mail -eq $_.mail}|%{
            #правим объект в другом домене
            $_|Set-ADUser -Server $server2 -DisplayName DisplayName -WhatIf
        }
    }
}
```